# Внедрение зависимостей с помощью интерфейсов в php

Tags: php, интерфейс

При изучении интерфейсов нашел пример их практического применения. 
Интерфейс:

```
interface iPost {
  public function find($id);
}
```

Класс:

```
class Post implements iPost {
  public function find($id){
    return $id;
  }
}
```

И дальше в статье приводится, что интерфейс решает проблему внедрения зависимости. Если раньше без интерфейса было

```
class PostController {
  private $post;

  public function __construct() {
   $this->post = new Post();
  }
}
```

То теперь с интерфейсом мы можем

```
class PostController {
  private $post;

  public function __construct(Post $post) {
   $this->post = $post;
  }
}
```

И дальше еще эффективнее запись

```
class PostController {
  private $post;

  public function __construct(iPost $post) {
   $this->post = $post;
  }
}
```

Обратите внимание в последнем примере в аргументах объект интерфейса.
Объясните, подробно, каким образом здесь улучшается внедрение зависимости и причем здесь интерфейс, чем так эффективнее последний код? Вообще не понял эту связь интерфейс<->эффективное внедрение зависимости. Каким образом здесь объект интерфейса, разве такое может быть?

Comment: Тем, что вы не привязаны к конкретной реализации Post. Допустим, другой разработчик захочет сделать класс `MegaPost` и сможет без проблем пользоваться `PostController`

Comment: В каком из приведенных примеров есть такая возможность?

Comment: В последнем, очевидно же. И имеется ввиду, что `MegaPost implements iPost`. Ваш пример не очень хорошо показывает преимущества. Возьмите лучше класс Logger с интерфейсом LoggerInterface. Вы берёте другую реализацию, которая вас устраивает больше, при этом наличие интерфейса гарантирует вам, что код будет работать. Если бы вы везде писали не интерфейс, а класс, то вам бы пришлось переписывать код во многих местах. А это всегда плохо

Comment: А как же тогда определится объект $post от какого он класса Post или megaPost?

Comment: Такие вещи настраиваются в DI контейнере. Если вы хотите, чтобы в одном месте работал MegaPost, а в другом Post, то тут всё сложно.

Comment: Где можно изучить этот вопрос или как это гуглить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изучи рефлексию, напиши свой DI контейнер который будет по интерфейсу подставлять указанную реализацию. И потом увидишь разницу, что можно сколько угодно раз подменивать iPost разными реализациями, а работа кода меняться не будет.

Вообще ужасный пример интерфейсов. Post это сущность которая часть системы и не нужно ее пытаться подменивать другими реализациями.
Более наглядно будет сделать абстракцию над БД так называемый repository для каждой сущности. Сделать интерфейс типа PostRepositoryInterface в котором будут методы save, remove, findOne, findBy и потом писать под них реализации. Одна реализация у тебя может работать с реальной БД, другая хранить в файле, третья вообще в памяти на время выполнение программы. И ты можешь их подменить в любой момент.